# Schengen visa extension

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-extensions

I have a Schengen visa that has a 90 days validity and will be expiring by the 25th of February, 2015. I got an Internship and thought I could renew or extend my visa from here (Geneva) but was told that I have to go back to my country (Nigeria) for a new visa. The visa procedure takes a month and there is a conference that I would like to attend by March which means if I should go back end of this month, I may not make it to the conference due to the long application period. Is there any way possible for me to have the extension here until March?

Comment: No you cannot it seems. I am assuming you have a short stay visa. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18384/how-to-extend-my-short-stay-visa-in-spain?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possible scenarios:

- Your visa expires on February 25th but you haven't used up your 90 days. You can either extend your visa or get a new one to come back to the Schengen area but you will probably need to return to Nigeria for that as visa extensions are only intended for “serious personal reasons”.
- Come February 25th, you will have stayed 90 days in the Schengen area. *You will not be able to get another Schengen short stay visa, even if you go back to Nigeria to apply for it*. You need to leave as soon as possible to avoid falling foul of the maximum stay rules or secure another type of visa from the Swiss authorities.

See also [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule), [Can I extend my 30 days Schengen visa in Switzerland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34595/can-i-extend-my-30-days-schengen-visa-in-switzerland) and [Is it possible to extend a tourist Schengen visa (12 more days)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31164/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-20-days-tourist-schengen-visa-12-more-days)

Comment: Hello i am back onece again with a question :) after going back to apply for a new Visa, do i have to wait for another 90days away from the Schenghen area or can i still apply for a long stay (6months) immediately to return back for my Internship in Geneva. Could that be possible? Thank you.

Comment: @fati Long-stay and short-stay visas are independent from each other. You cannot get a new short-stay visa but you can apply for a *long-stay* visa and reenter immediately if you get it.

Comment: @Relaxed How about if the extension / new visa is a short term as well ?