# Can I extend my 45-day visa in Spain?

Tags: schengen, visa-extensions

I am a Turkish citizen. I have a 45-day Greek Schengen tourist visa. Can I extend my visa for 5 days in Spain?

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18384/how-to-extend-my-short-stay-visa-in-spain?rq=1 and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26794/is-it-possible-to-extend-my-90-day-short-stay-in-sweden-by-10-or-15-days?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

It's usually **impossible** to extend a Schengen visa for tourism. There are a couple of exceptions/alternatives:

- You can request an extension of your Schengen visa if you have a very serious reason (e.g. illness or family emergency) but not merely for convenience or because you changed your plans.
- You might be able to apply for an entirely different visa (a national visa, not a Schengen visa, e.g. a spouse visa if you are married to a Spanish citizen) but I don't know precisely what's available in Spain and that's most likely not applicable to your situation.